# UNIX awk : Print line with "CLICKS", if * on pos 7 skip line, if contain "\" concat next line, if next line has * concat 3rd line

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I need to print line from file which contains "CLICK" and are not commented (* on position 7) like line 000001,

if the line has CLICK and "\" then concatenate the next line too , if next line is commented then skip that line and concatenate the next one : like line number 000002 concat with line 000004 skipping line 000003.

if concatenated line (next) also contains '\' then we do not need to concat the 3rd line, by which i mean we do Delete the line from the output, like we deleted the lines 3 and 5 because they are not required 
the core logic as stated previously:
[if the line has CLICK and "\" (both) then concatenate the next line, if line only has CLICK print that line only,everything other line is deleted from output ] .

so in this case  example is:
 000006 concats line 000007 but do not concats 000008 which means 000008 will be deleted from the output

INPUT FILE:

```
000001  HECTOR CLICK MOUSE
000002  ANNE CLICK MOUSE \
000003* AND PRESSES KEYBOARD
000004  AND PRESS KEYBOARD
000005* CLARK CLICK MOUSE
000006 MIKE CLICK MOUSE \
000007 AND PRESS KEYBOARD \
000008 AND TAPS SCREEN
```

output

```
000001  HECTOR CLICK MOUSE
000002  ANNE CLICK MOUSE \ AND PRESS KEYBOARD
000006 MIKE CLICK MOUSE \ AND PRESS KEYBOARD \
```

I have created this :

```
awk '
/^...... +/{
if  ($0 ~ /CLICK/ && $0 ~ /\\/)
      {l1=$0;getline; print l1 $0}
else if 
    ($0 ~ /CLICK/ && $0 !~ /\\/)
     {print $0} ;
}' *> outfile
```

the outcome is quite close but there are two problems :

```
1. the data is written twice
2. commented second line is also printed, i tried /^...... +/ inside the if but it gave error
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear, it is not at all clear like from which logic you want to skip the lines.

Comment: i need to print a line containing pattern CLICK which is not commented, like line number 000001 and 000002 in the input,
      but if the line also contains pattern '\' then i need to concatenate the next line too, now if that next line is commented then skip that line and concatenate the 3rd line 
example : line 000002 is printed and the 000004 one but 000003 is skipped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ /\*$/ { next }
saved != "" {
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+/," ")
    print saved $0
    saved = ""
}
/CLICK/ {
    if ( /\\$/ ) {
        saved = $0
    }
    else {
        print
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
000001  HECTOR CLICK MOUSE
000002  ANNE CLICK MOUSE \ AND PRESS KEYBOARD
000006 MIKE CLICK MOUSE \ AND PRESS KEYBOARD \
```

Skip every comment line. For every other line: When we find a line containing CLICK, if it ends in backslash then save it, otherwise print it. For every line, if we have a saved string then print it in front of the current line. The sub() is to change the leading number and spaces into a single blank char before printing the current line at the end of the saved line.

Comment: hey Ed, could you please explain your solution, why we are using sub(/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]] does not make sense to me, also i tried this with my whole directory but it is not returning any records in my outfile.. i appreciate your effort though .. PS: i am using kornshell

Comment: I added some explanatory text. Let me know if you have any specific questions. You can also add debugging print statements to it yourself to see what it's doing. If it's not working for your real files then our real files do not look like the sample input you provided. awk has absolutely nothing to do with any shell, the posted script will work in any UNIX shell or in Windows.

Comment: i do not get why we using 
saved != "" {
    sub(/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+/," ")
    print saved $0
    saved = ""
}     ..what is the use of [:space]

Comment: You've got a saved line like `000002  ANNE CLICK MOUSE \ ` and a current line that looks like `000004<blank><blank>AND PRESS KEYBOARD ` and you want the output to be `000002  ANNE CLICK MOUSE \<blank>AND PRESS KEYBOARD ` so we need to get rid of the `000002` from the start of the current line and convert any spaces after it to a single blank char. Hence the sub(). `[[:space:]]` is a bracket expression containing a POSIX character class `[:space:]` that represents all white space characters and the negation of it `[^[:space:]]` is a bracket expression representing all non-white space characters

Comment: unfortunately actuall y this does not filter the commented line

Comment: while using CAT it is not working as it says saved not found, when i use awk' instead of cat it works but do not filter the commented code for source in $(cat pme.lsk) do awk ' /^...... +/{ next } saved != "" { sub(/^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+/," ") print saved $0 saved = "" } /CLICK/ { if ( /\\$/ ) { saved = $0 } else { print } }' $source *> outfilek1 done

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't imagine what `while using CAT it is not working as it says saved not found` and `when i use awk' instead of cat it works` mean. Are you trying to use `cat` to evaluate the awk script? When you run the script I posted against the input you posted, does it or does it not produce the output you posted? If the answer is it does not, then edit your question and copy/paste **exactly** the contents of your input file and the text on your screen (prompts, commands, everything) as you execute exactly my posted awk command and the output it produces so we can help.

Comment: The shell script you posted in your comment is riddled with bugs btw (incorrect for loop structure, missing `;`, unquoted variable, misplaced `*`, UUOC, use of reserved word as a variable, etc, etc...) but idk if those are problems in your real code or are an artifact of you trying to re-type your code in the comment. In any case, we can't really read code or anything else that requires formatting in a comment so update your question with anything relevant.

Comment: thanks alot.. i have fixed my code and it works like a dream .. i have removed the cat btw